# Netsuite Saved Search - Highlight row based on two column comparison in result

Tags: netsuite

We have a saved search in Netsuite that looks at all open quotes with a greater than 70% chance of converting in the next 30 days.  In the results, we're looking at the items on these quotes and how many of these said items we have on hand to help us forecast inventory needs.  The search is working fine, but we would like to highlight the rows in the result where quantity quoted is greater than on hand.  I've been able to highlight result rows based on the value of one column, but cannot figure out how to compare two columns.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your saved search or knowing what your environment looks like (multiple locations?), this is the pattern for a formula that I use when I need to filter records in a saved search by comparing two fields.

On the criteria tab, add the following field

Filter: Formula (Numeric)

Value: equal to 1

Formula:

```
case 
    when {quantity} > {item.quantityonhand} then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

**EDIT**: If you're aggregating your results, then the formula should go on the Summary sub tab of the Criteria tab.  Summary type should be 'Sum'.  Field should be 'Formula (Numeric)'.  Value should be 'Equal to 1' and the formula in your case would be:

```
case 
    when sum({quantity}) > max({item.quantityonhand}) then 1 
    else 0 
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried that solution but didn't have the expected result.  I think it's because I have summaries on the result.  I tried to duplicate those summaries in the formula, but using things like SUM() led to errors. My search is laid out as follows:

Criteria: http://i.imgur.com/trHSKeQ.jpg

Results: http://i.imgur.com/tqRrk1g.jpg

Comment: Updated my answer to show how to use this formula when your saved search is grouping the results.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you again for the reply.  This wasn't doing what I was looking to do; it was eliminating items from the result where we had more on hand than the quantity quoted, and the purchasing department wants to see both instances.  However, it did point me in the right direction.  I used that formula on the, 'Highlighting if... (Summary)' subtab of the Highlighting tab, and now the rows which have less items on hand that what has been quoted are highlighted.  Thank you!